# How can I update a user's account with purchased products if the PUT request requires administrator permissions?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, stripe-payments

I have a website that sells specific products and uses Stripe for payment processing. The process consists of two possible steps:

first step: Users without an account add products to their cart. The backend then generates a checkout URL from Stripe. After a successful payment, the user is redirected to the `/setup` route to create their account.

or second step: users who already have an account make a purchase and are directed to a successful route. They receive information about the product and are informed that it is available for download in the `/dashboard`.

The problem arises when I need to update the user's account with the newly purchased products. One possible solution I considered was to send a `PUT` request to the backend after the user clicks on "go to dashboard" in the `/success` route. This request would retrieve the available products that the user already has and concatenate them with the new products they just bought. However, the issue is that my `PUT` route for users can only be accessed by administrators, and most users do not have this permission.

I cannot modify my `PUT` route to allow users to update their products because it would create a security risk, as anyone could potentially add products.

I would appreciate any suggestions for alternative solutions to address this issue.

I've tried just updating the dashboard.

Comment: It sounds like it needs to be done on the backend. For example you might be able to subscribe to purchase events on stripe and update users when that happens. Or you can redirect to /save-products route which will do PUT request on the back-end and then redirect to /setup, or something along those lines, hope it helps. TLDR try to do it on BE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what the comment mentioned, you would want to perform any DB actions on your backend.

When creating the Checkout Session, you can add the `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` template variable to the `success_url`. The `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` will be automatically substituted with a real Checkout Session ID after your customer pays and is redirected to the success page. See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page for more information.

When the customer is redirected to your /success route, you can then make a request to your backend server to retrieve the Checkout Session from Stripe (and/or any other relevant information) with the Checkout Session id, verify that Checkout Session belongs to the same customer/user who made the request, and update your DB.

However, the general recommendation is to listen for the relevant webhook events to perform post payment actions, rather than waiting on a callback from the client. On the client, the customer could close the browser window or quit the app before the callback executes.

You can setup a webhook endpoint to listen for the `checkout.session.completed` (or other) event(s) from Stripe. Upon receipt of that event, verify that the event was sent by Stripe and perform whatever actions you want to handle in your server.

Additional resources for webhooks :

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
- https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/stripe-events
- https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart